# How can one check today's day of the week in Youtrack Workflow

Tags: youtrack

I would like a certain schedule rule (with notifications) to be executed only during work days. I.e. I would like to avoid receiving notifications on Saturdays and Sundays. How can I check for a current day of the week in YouTrack Workflow?

Answer (score 3):

Using format you can get day of week abbreviation or full name.

```
var dayOfWeekAbr = now.format(#E);
var dayOfWeek = now.format(#EEEE);
```

Or using year-month-day literal (2014-01-05 was Sunday):

```
var day = (created - 2014-01-05).millis / 86400000 % 7; 
if (day > 1 && day < 6) { 
  message("Work day"); 
}
```

Comment: Is there some reference where one could see all the date formatting options?

I only found http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD5/Workflow+Language+Quick+Reference , but it's only an overview.

The reason I'm asking is because it's hard to test the workflow scripts with the in cloud Youtrack, since I don't want to mess up our production setup.

I.e. is there a format option that would return a day of week number?

Comment: think using format you can't take day of week number. I guess format string is subset of  [gwt DateTimeFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't built-in YouTrack workflow mechanism of defining a current day of week, but the simple workaround allows to do it:

```
schedule rule day of week

daily at 10:00:00 [for all issues] { 
  var monday = {issue: A-1}.created - 1 day; 

  while (i < 50) { 
    if (monday + (i * 7) days < now && now < monday + (i * 7 + 5) days) { 
      //now is the work day
  }
}
```

The issue `A-1` is a sample issue created on Tuesday, so `{issue: A-1}.created - 1 day` refers to the `Monday`.

The `while` cycle finds the current week and `if()` defines whether today is a work day or a weekend.

Comment: Should "i" be defined and then incremented?

Comment: I'm also thinking whether such obscurity would be worth it :)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, I didn't find the previous solutions readable.
The solution I've implemented:

```
var today = now.format(utc).substring(0, 3); 
if (today == "Mon" || today == "Tue" || today == "Wed" || today == "Thu" || today == "Fri") { 
  message("Work day!"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the shortest solution specifically for avoiding weekends, as Saturday and Sunday are the only days beginning with an uppercase 'S':

`if(!now.format(#E).startsWith("S", opts)) {}`

/e: as Artem correctly pointed out, this may have to be adopted or does not work for certain localizations - it does at least for German and English.

Comment: Fun idea, but there can be localization issues with this approach :)